# Redmine ruby run

Tags: ruby, redmine

i installed redmine with this manual:
http://www.redmine.org/wiki/Redmine/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu
but when i try to run redmine i got:

```
 #!/usr/bin/ruby

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment" unless defined?(RAILS_ROOT)

require "dispatcher" 

ADDITIONAL_LOAD_PATHS.reverse.each { |dir| $:.unshift(dir) if File.directory?(dir) } if defined?(Apache::RubyRun)
Dispatcher.dispatch
```

as text. what could it be? ruby is not running?
done.forgot to configure nginx :)

Comment: what do you mean when you try to run redmine? when you booted up the server you saw this in the console, or when you launched the web browser after you started the server?

Answer (score 0):

suggest using mod_rails or mongrel

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, check out [these instructions](http://madpropellerhead.com/random/20100820-installing-redmine-on-debian-with-apache). They're for Debian, but I believe it works pretty much similarly for Ubuntu.